# Why does this pom.xml have references to javascript libraries?

Tags: maven, spring-boot, webjars

I came across this [pom.xml](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-static/pom.xml) file of a `sample spring boot` project. I was surprised to see dependency section for client side javascript libraries like `bootstrap` and `jquery` inside it.

I would like to know what are these dependencies, what do they offer and is there any advantage of using them in a Spring Boot application?

Comment: You need to work on your investigative skills: http://www.webjars.org/

Comment: @kryger I went through that link already, but couldn't understand what exactly it is.

Answer (score 2):

This is a special project called [`WebJars`](http://www.webjars.org/).

It aims to package most popular JavaScript libraries into JAR files that could be used in the Java projects as a Maven/Gradle/etc dependencies.

Some of its benefits are:

- you don't need to import all the JS libraries into your version control system (Git, for example)
- you can easily manage JS libraries and its versions by updating and rolling them back, like you do with other Maven dependencies
- other benefits (like resolving transitive dependencies) are listed on the official site

See also: [Utilizing WebJars in Spring Boot](https://spring.io/blog/2014/01/03/utilizing-webjars-in-spring-boot)

Comment: Does it make any sense to have these dependencies in a **pure services project(no html files)**?

Comment: Most likely, no, you don't need them. Unless you're developing server that will serve JS/CSS files to other consumers (like a local CDN).

Answer (score -1):

This allows a dependency management for js libraries/frameworks over maven. That's all.

Alternately, you could do this as well with bower or node.js